# operator between Banach spaces and its boundeness

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I am trying to understand the proof of the following:

Let $T:X\to Y$ be an operator between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ and $T$ is linear. Let $\mathrm{dim}\,X=n\,<\infty$. Then $T$ is bounded.

The proof is trivial but for one step:
Let's choose a fixed basis in $X$ as $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^n$, then

$|| Tx || \le \sum_{j=1}^n |\alpha_j| || Tx_j || \leq \max_{j=1..n}|| Tx_j ||\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n |\alpha_j| = c||x||_1\leq c_2||x|| $

How do I know that $\max_{j=1..n}|| Tx_j ||<\infty$?

Comment: There are finitely many numbers. The maximum is thus finite.

Comment: The requirement $T:X\to Y$ guarantees that $Tx_j$ belongs to $Y$ for each $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Therefore, you get $n$ elements of $Y$. And these elements have a norm (which is a real number). Consequently, $\|Tx_j\|$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$ are $n$ real numbers, and one of them is the greatest.

Comment: @sranthrop My issue is more like, what if $Tx = 1/(1-x)$ and one of $x_j$ is 1? That is, how do i know that application of the operator on a particular basis member ends up finite (not really that i have finite number of elements and doing maximum from the finite amount of numbers)?

Comment: @leosenko The operator $T$ defined by $Tx = 1/(1-x)$ is not linear. In general, $T$ maps from $X$ to $Y$ so for every $x\in X$,  $Tx\in Y$, but every element of $Y$ has finite norm so you can't have the kind of problem you mention.

Comment: @StratosFair But what makes every element of $Y$ have a finite form? Because in my notes, we define the norm of a linear $T$ as $||T||=\sup_{||x||\le 1}||Tx||$ and we say that this norm can be infinite...

Comment: Yeah the supremum of a set of real numbers can be infinite without the set itself containing the number infinity. Consider for instance $\mathbb N = \{0, 1,\ldots,n\}$, the supremum is $\infty$ but every element of the set is finite.

Comment: @StratosFair I am sorry, I am probably too dumb, but what makes every element of $Y$ to have a finite norm?

Comment: Because the map $\|\cdot\|_Y $ maps from $Y$ to the set of non-negative reals $\mathbb R^+$ by definition. But $\infty$ is not a real number hence it can't take that value for any element of $Y$.

Comment: @StratosFair Oh, so it is a property of a norm, that by definition it cannot be infinite. That is what i was missing.